# $facebook->api('me/albums') showing two wall photos albums

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using `$facebook->api('me/albums')` for getting all the albums that a user created.But in the result two wall photos albums are showing.But in my facebook profile it is not visible.I have tried fql query for getting all the albums.There also two wall photos are showing.Is their any way to remove the wall photos  by changing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem here: you're saying that when you access a particular user's albums you find two named 'Wall Photos' - why is that a problem? They could have created a second album with that name, there's no restriction on album names on Facebook that they need to be different.

If i'm misunderstanding this please clarify your question but it sounds like your main question is either

'can i delete an album via the API?' (no) or

'Should there be two identically named albums?' (there's no reason there can't be)

Comment: For every user am getting 2 Wall photos

Comment: yeah, i see two for myself too, one is posts on my own wall, the other is posts on my friends' walls - i still don't understand why that's a problem for your app but you could always just merge the two sets of photos together and display it as a single album to the user if you need to

Comment: Now am using FQL query for getting the facebook albums.Then also am getting the same problems.Is i can  use distinct property ...